# How to filter a string?

Tags: python, filter

im making a bot that get info from an api, the problem is that it gives me a lot of data and I only need something in particular. I need just to get the balance, miner status and hashrate.

```
import os
import discord
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

token = "DISCORD_TOKEN"
url = "https://eth.crazypool.org/api/accounts/0x54DcB3b38d05940d3A88ADeff5B57f15f7F64A02"
headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.193 Safari/537.36'}

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="Mining eth"))
    print("On!")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    jk = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
    if message.content == "!miner":
        await message.channel.send(jk)
    if message.content == "!balance":
        await message.channel.send(jk)
    if message.content == "!shares":
        await message.channel.send(jk)


client.run(token)
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: The contents of string looks like it's in JSON format, so could be converted into Python data using the built-in `json` module. So doing might make what you want to do easier.

Answer (score 2):

You can use requests.json() what you would have to do is

```
page = page.json()
balance = page["stats"]["balance"]
```

And what this does is it goes into the "stats" section of the json data then into the "balance" which then if you do `print(balance)` it will print the balance.

Answer (score 2):

requests.json() will give you the output as a json then you can just treat it like it was the json library.

Answer (score 1):

Use requests.json() and then just go into the "stats" then "balance"